# JwtHeader.SigningKeyIdentifier creates incorrect X509ThumbprintKeyIdentifierClause

Tags: c#, jwt, adal

I am trying to validate a JWT token. The code is within an OWIN OAuth handler, however I have taken the various pieces out into a small console application and it would appear to be a problem with how the JwtHeader method SigningKeyIdentifier creates a X509ThumbprintKeyIdentifierClause object.

My JWT has a header value of x5t = [base64urlencodedvalue], and I have confirmed that when this string is decoded it is indeed the thumbprint for my certificate. However, in the SigningKeyIdentifier class the following code seems to create a incorrect clause, e.g. the hash of the clause doesnt match the certificate.

```
identifier.Add(new X509ThumbprintKeyIdentifierClause(Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(this.GetStandardClaim("x5t"))));
```

Below is a snippet of the console app that tries to demostrate the issue:

```
        // http://kjur.github.io/jsjws/tool_b64udec.html
        const string X5T = "NmJmOGUxMzZlYjM2ZDRhNTZlYTA1YzdhZTRiOWE0NWI2M2JmOTc1ZA"; // value inside the JWT (x5t)
        const string thumbPrint = "6bf8e136eb36d4a56ea05c7ae4b9a45b63bf975d"; // correct thumbprint of certificate

        string thumbPrintBase64 = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(thumbPrint);  // <--- value in x5t of JWT 

        // finds correct certificate
        var cert1 = X509CertificateHelper.FindByThumbprint(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, thumbPrint).First();

        var certHash = cert1.GetCertHash();
        string hexa = BitConverter.ToString(certHash).Replace("-", string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine(hexa.ToLowerInvariant());

        // TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey
        var clause1 = new X509ThumbprintKeyIdentifierClause(cert1);

        string hex1 = BitConverter.ToString(clause1.GetX509Thumbprint()).Replace("-", string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine(clause1.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(hex1.ToLowerInvariant());


        // this is how JwtHeader.SigningKeyIdentifier method creates SecurityKeyIdentifier 
        var hash = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(thumbPrintBase64);
        var clause2 = new X509ThumbprintKeyIdentifierClause(hash);    // <----- broken

        string hexb = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine(hexb.ToLowerInvariant());
        Console.WriteLine(clause2.ToString());
        string hex2 = BitConverter.ToString(clause2.GetX509Thumbprint()).Replace("-", string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine(hex2.ToLowerInvariant());

        // clause1 and clause2 should be the same, but they arent!?
```

The problem seems to be that the various consructors for  X509ThumbprintKeyIdentifierClause end up with different hash values which when compared later dont match.

In my OWIN project one piece creates a X509ThumbprintKeyIdentifierClause from a certificate (TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey). e.g.

```
IssuerSigningKey = new X509SecurityKey(X509CertificateHelper.FindByThumbprint(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, thumbPrint).First()),
```

and the IssuerSigningKeyResolver method called to match the JWT with the issue certificate using the thumbnail from the x5t field.

```
identifier.Add(new X509ThumbprintKeyIdentifierClause(Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(this.GetStandardClaim("x5t"))));
```

but they dont match.

What am I missing? Something feels wrong with the encoding/decoding of the thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

We had a great discussion about this in GitHub, should have posted here before.

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/100

The input that is encoded and creates the x5t is not the 'thumbprint', which are  encoded octets. but the octets from the certhash.

The JwtHeader creates the clause as:

ski.Add(new X509ThumbprintKeyIdentifierClause(Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(GetStandardClaim(JwtHeaderParameterNames.X5t))));

Not:
var hash = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(thumbPrintBase64);

Comment: I checked and I think they are the same thing. The X5t is the Base64UrlEncoded value of the Thumbnail bytes. The Thumbnail is HEX encoded, so you need to decode the string as hex -> bytes and then Base64 encode it to get the value in the x5t